# javascript ajax method: flushing setter

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I've got a following javascript object:

```
var UsersControl = {
    users: null,
    fetchData: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            context: this,
            url: "../php/client/json.php",
            data: {
                type: "users"
            }
        }).done(function(response) {
            this.users = response;
        });
    },
    getData: function() {
        if (this.users == null) {
            this.fetchData();
        }
        return this.users;
    }
};
```

When I run the `getData()` method, `users` field is already defined, but old value (`null`) is returned in this call. In next calls, the appropriate value (ajax-ed) is returned. Example javascript console session:

```
> UsersControl
> Object {users: null, fetchData: function, getData: function}

> UsersControl.getData()
> null

> UsersControl
> Object {users: Array[2], fetchData: function, getData: function}

> UsersControl.getData()
> [Object, Object]
```

It looks like javascript remembers current state of the object when a method is called - and all state changes will be applied after the method is finished. But this makes impossible to run modify object fields on the fly (just like in every OOP language I've used before). Or, simply, I have a bug somewhere. I'd be grateful for any hints on this topic.

Comment: aah, I used few `console.log` to see that `fetchData` is returned before the AJAX call has been finished. What can I do to make the `fetchData` method wait for the ajax call to be finished?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me... it was a matter of synchronicity...

```
fetchData: function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        url: "../php/client/json.php",
        async:   false,               // <- note this
        data: {
            type: "users"
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        this.users = response;
    });
},
```